# Как реализовать отображение WinForms поверх игры в полноэкранном режиме?

Tags: c#

Мне нужно реализовать оверлей (например, как в Дискорде) через WinForms. Игра - GTA:SA. Возможно ли это? Если да, то как можно это реализовать? Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

TopMost не предлагать ( с GTA:SA не работает.Игра просто сворачивается )

Comment: Поверх полноэкранного режима быстро и просто не получится, придется копаться DirectX API. Но может получиться поверх полноэкранного окна, многие игры поддерживают такой режим. А так, есть такое приложение Overwolf, насколько я помню, оно поддерживает плагины, и можно попробовать отрисовать то что нужно поверх игры через его API.

Comment: Что-то типа такого https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/c/62019-c-non-hooked-external-directx-overlay.html знаю.. не самая лучшая ссылка, но помогает понять, как такое делать

Comment: А с DirectX разве получится сделать кликабелную кнопку например?

Answer (score 0):

При полном экране через WinForms - никак. У приложения монополия над экраном, но можно влезть в команды отрисовки приложения. Если посмотреть на такие приложения как MSI Afterburner, AIDA64, YAKD и тп, то они используют shared memory программы [RTSS](https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/rtss-rivatuner-statistics-server-download.html), которая как раз-таки и отрисовывает переданные ей данные прямо в поверх приложения. [Есть библиотека](https://github.com/spencerhakim/RTSSSharedMemoryNET) на C++, её можно использовать в .NET приложении создав свой OSD и выводить уже вашу информацию поверх экрана. А делать интерактивный оверлей куда сложнее.

Есть ещё [Overlay.NET](https://github.com/lolp1/Overlay.NET) пакет, но он предлагает вам самим с нуля рисовать оверлей примитивами.